# Use of .contains in an ArrayList<String> went wrong

Tags: java, string, arraylist

I have to check a list of Strings and if the String is not processed before, then we do some on the String. For his matter, I add each String to an `ArrayList<String>` after processing and check if the String exists in the list of not, before processing. But for some reason, it does not work although the String exists in the array list.

```
ArrayList<String> strings=new ArrayList<String>();
while(true) {
   if(!strings.contains(someString)) {
      System.out.println(someString);
      strings.add(someString);
   }
}
```

**EDIT**

When I mentioned it does not work, I mean that the `if` condition should return false for similar strings (as they contains each other), but instead, it does not do as such and then the program goes into the `if` statement.

Input:

`http://www.foo.bar` and `http://www.foo.bar/` and `http://www.foo.bar` etc.

Output:

Should only prints the first URL.

Comment: What do you mean with "It does not work"?. Please describe exactly what you expected to happen, and what is actually happening. Include any exceptions/stacktraces that you encounter.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt It does not work means for same or very similar string it does not return false. so it goes inside the `if` statement which is not right.

Comment: Post the *exact* code that doesn't work. You're saying "very similar" - well, very similar is not *exactly the same* so of course the `contains` method returns `false`.

Comment: Use a hash set if all you want to do is determine if the string already exists or not.

Comment: Please provide examples with actual output and expected output. just like what Erwin said. @lonesome

Comment: @JanLeeYu I have done it.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt I have added a short example. Please take a look.

Comment: So, your actual output prints the two URLs @lonesome?

Comment: @JanLeeYu Of course not, Only first one. cause the other two are either same thing or the first one contains it.

Comment: sorry. Its the actual output rather @lonesome

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104353/discussion-between-janleeyu-and-lonesome).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're putting different strings in the `ArrayList` ("http://www.foo.bar" and "http://www.foo.bar/") and you are expecting them to be considered the same by the `contains` method. That doesn't work; `contains` only works when the strings are exactly the same.

Given that there are hundreds of conceivable ways in which you could consider strings to be "similar", it is not surprising that there is no built-in support for such a "similarity check".

An easy way to do what you want is to *[canonicalize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonicalization)* your strings before putting them in the list.

In your case, you want the strings to be considered the same regardless of whether they end in a slash or not. You could canonicalize them by ensuring that the string *always* ends in a slash before putting them in the list:

```
if (!someString.endsWith("/")) {
    someString += "/";
}
```

(An other option is to consider [edit-distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance) between strings; however you need a special data structure to store them for that, a normal ArrayList will not suffice.)

Answer (score 3):

Try to do it like this :

```
while(true) {//dont know why you have this endless loop
   boolean flag = false;
   for (String s : strings) {
       if (s.toUpperCase().contains(someStrings.toUpperCase()) || someStrings.toUpperCase().contains(s.toUpperCase())) {
           flag = true;
           //the string already exists
           break;
       }
   }
   if (flag) {
   //to do if string already exists
   } else {
       strings.add(someStrings);
   }
}
```

I get it now. please check again.

Comment: I think it don't work correctly. 
First run, list add `http://www.foo.bar`.
Then, list will add `http://www.foo.bar/`. Because `bar` don't contain `bar/`

Comment: I updated my answer. please check. @lonesome

Comment: please my answer too @Manh Le

Comment: It's work correctly.
@lonesome for advanced compare, you should use `Regular expression` to cover your situation. We need to modify compare condition based on your example, but with your real data, it's may not work.

Comment: Because the Erwin's answer is shorter and matches my code easier, So I only upvote yours.

Comment: That's fine. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I stand corrected- the below does the same as ArrayList.contains().

```
private static ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) myList.add("aString" + i);
    if (myList.contains("aString3")) System.out.println("Contains is true");
    else System.out.println("Contains is false");
}
```

prints "Contains is true". Sorry for the bad information.

When you use ArrayList.contains(Object), you are checking to see if the list contains that exact object. In your case, you want to do a String by String comparison and not an object comparison.

```
for (String string : strings) {
  if (someString.contains(string)) {
    //Do stuff
  }
}
```

Comment: But if one string is like `book` and the other is `books` i want to consider them as same thing. does `.equal`take care of this?

Comment: Wouldn't using a toString() also work in his case, since it would convert the object to a string? Just thinking out loud. Haven't thought this through.

Comment: then I think, you might just replace .equals with .contains(). right?

Comment: What you posted is exactly what the `contains` method does. There is no difference. So it won't resolve the issue.

Comment: @lonesome: I think @JanLeeYu's recommed will solve your problem. When you use `.contains` on `ArrayList`, your object must exactly equal.